# How to resize splitter in PhpStorm

Tags: intellij-idea, split, keyboard-shortcuts, phpstorm

I see that I can resize the side sidebar by using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Arrows</kbd>.

How can I do the same thing for a Vertical/Horizontal Split.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At the moment you cannot do this via keyboard -- mouse only.

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-67379 -- watch this ticket (star/vote/comment) to get notified on progress.

Answer (score 9):

There is a plugin called "Tab Shifter" that allows to resize a spliter [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qkAP4.png). After you add it and restart Intellij you can stretch a split screen right with <kbd>ctral</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>]</kbd> and left with <kbd>ctral</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>[</kbd>.

In theory stretching up and down should also work, but for me it was installed without this shortcut configured. However keboard shortcuts for stretching up and down can be defined under[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PA9ph.png):

```
`Settings`->`Keymap`->`Plug-ins`->`Tab Shifter`->`Stretch Splitter Up` 
`Settings`->`Keymap`->`Plug-ins`->`Tab Shifter`->`Stretch Splitter Down`
```

[image: add plugin]
[image: add shortcut for stretching down]